# Setting a page to open in a new borderless window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to force a page to open in a new window all the time regardless of the link used to open it? By adding something to the header perhaps? I know about target-"new" and window.open() but i want the page itself to always open as a new window with no toolbars or scrollbars shown even if the link used to open it is generic () with no target="new" or similar specified. I am only concerned with Internet explorer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no. What you are talking about is taking control of a browser even before  it opens which means access to stuff the web page has no business accessing.  Window.open, etc is the best you can hope for

Comment: Add target attr to your links and thats the best and the best solution

Answer (score 5):

I actually found a nice example [here](http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/window-toolbar-scrollbar-etc-313.html)

here's the snippet (you might need to type this in a text editor and open that html file first because I don't seem to be getting it working on StackOverflow alone)

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Opening Multiple Popup Windows</title>

<script language="javascript">
<!--//
function myPopup(url,windowname,w,h,x,y){
window.open(url,windowname,"resizable=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,status=no,directories=n o,width="+w+",height="+h+",left="+x+",top="+y+"");
console.log("Opening: " + windowname);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Inside the parenthesis the order goes URL, window name, width, height, position from left, position from top-->
<!-- Note that by giving each popup window a different name each page will open in a seperate popup window-->
<a href="javascript:myPopup('http://www.cnn.com', 'CNN','300','300','10','300')">Open popup 1</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:myPopup('http://example.com', 'Example.com','300','300','100','300')">Open popup 2</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:myPopup('http://www.nbc.com', 'NBC','300','300','200','500')">Open popup 3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Popup will not support by moder browsers

Comment: Ok thanks to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337916/why-is-window-open-blocked) I now know that Stack overflow doesn't allow this but it should work fine on its own (assuming your browser allows pop-ups)